# In a user's Edit Info form, how do I include the name of the field(s) and user's input value(s) in a response from the model

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, yii2

On a Yii2 project, in a user's Edit Info form (inside a modal):

I'm currently figuring out which fields were changed using the jQuery `.change()` method, and I'm grabbing their value with jQuery's `.val()` method.

## However, I want to do less with JavaScript and do more with Yii's framework.

I can see in the Yii debugger (after clicking into the AJAX POST request) that Yii is smart enough to know which fields were changed -- it's showing SQL queries that only `UPDATE` the fields that were changed.

What do I need to change in the controller of this action to have Yii include the  name of the field changed -- including it's value --  in the AJAX response? (since my goal is to update the main view with the new values)

```
public function actionUpdateStudentInfo($id)
{
    $model = \app\models\StudentSupportStudentInfo::findOne($id);
        if ($model === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }

    $model->scenario = true ? "update-email" : "update-studentid";
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        return $this->renderAjax('_student_support_alert_success');
    }
    return $this->renderAjax("_edit_student_info",[
        "model" => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I'm currently returning a static success view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$model->dirtyAttributes` just after load the data to get a `$attrib => $value` pair array.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#getDirtyAttributes()-detail (this docs says:)

> Returns the attribute values that have been modified since they are loaded or saved most recently.
>
> The comparison of new and old values is made for identical values using ===.

`public array getDirtyAttributes ( $names = null )`

(sorry for formatting, sent by mobile)

Comment: This definitely puts me on the right path, thank you! I need to really go through the Yii2 guide